# How to support key rollover for JWT signature verification?

Tags: identityserver4, identityserver3

I have a project which uses `IdentitySever3.AccessTokenValidation` library:

```
app.UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication(new IdentityServerBearerTokenAuthenticationOptions
{
    IssuerName = issuerUrl,
    SigningCertificate = LoadCertificate(),
    RequiredScopes = new[] { "openid", "offline_access" },
    ValidationMode = ValidationMode.Local
});
```

I would like to match public key by `kid` claim of token's header. But how do I provide multiple keys? And where do I define how mach is performed?

Comment: I guess with the only certificate you can't. but you can with specifying the Authority and involving discovery.

Comment: @d_f do you mean discovery endpoint?

Comment: yes, Identityserver supports exposing multiple keys at a time